# Like best performance in nested query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like, sqlperformance

I have a principal requet with 2 requets in. I have a problem in my second nested query, I have a condition on `id` and if I made my request `id = 10` takes a long time to execute, so if I replace it by `id LIKE 10` my request execute in one second.

Here the request:

```
 SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE contact_groupe.id_contact_groupe
 FROM toto.contact_groupe
 LEFT JOIN toto.`contact` AS `contact`
 ON ((toto.contact_groupe.id_contact_groupe = toto.contact.id_contact_groupe))
 LEFT JOIN toto.`project` AS `project`
 ON ((toto.contact_groupe.id_contact_groupe = toto.project.id_contact_groupe)
 AND ( toto.project.id_project
 IN (
     SELECT MAX(toto.project.id_project)
        FROM toto.project
        WHERE ( toto.contact_groupe.id_contact_groupe = toto.project.id_contact_groupe )
) ))
LEFT JOIN toto.`phase` AS `phase`
ON ((project.id_phase = toto.phase.id_phase))
LEFT JOIN sql_base.`user` AS `user_suivi`
ON ((toto.contact_groupe.id_user_suivi = user_suivi.id_user))
WHERE ( en_attente = '0' AND contact_groupe.id_contact_groupe
IN (
     SELECT DISTINCT(contact_groupe.id_contact_groupe)
     FROM toto.contact_groupe
     LEFT JOIN toto.`contact` AS `contact`
     ON ((toto.contact_groupe.id_contact_groupe = toto.contact.id_contact_groupe)
     LEFT JOIN toto.`source_contact_groupe` AS `source_contact_groupe`
     ON ((toto.contact_groupe.id_contact_groupe = toto.source_contact_groupe.id_contact_groupe))
     LEFT JOIN toto.`project` AS `project`
     ON ((toto.contact_groupe.id_contact_groupe = toto.project.id_contact_groupe))
     LEFT JOIN toto.`remarque` AS `remarque`
     ON ((toto.contact_groupe.id_contact_groupe = toto.remarque.id_contact_groupe))
     LEFT JOIN toto.`project_type_construction_options` AS `project_type_construction_options`
     ON ((project.id_project = toto.project_type_construction_options.id_project))
     LEFT JOIN toto.`project_concurrent` AS `project_concurrent`
     ON ((project.id_project = toto.project_concurrent.id_project))
     LEFT JOIN toto.`telephone` AS `telephone`
     ON ((contact.id_contact = toto.telephone.id_contact))
     WHERE ( en_attente = '0' AND ( toto.project.id_project = '10' )      AND toto.contact_groupe.id_entreprise = '2' )
)
AND toto.contact_groupe.id_entreprise = '2' )
ORDER BY toto.contact_groupe.id_contact_groupe ASC
```

the line is the following problem `toto.project.id_project = '10'` and I don't understand why the time to execute request is so different between `=` and `LIKE`

Comment: Tag dbms used. Product specific issue. (ANSI SQL, and most dbms products, don't allow LIKE on integer values.) Column data type?

Comment: I Use MYSQL, so `LIKE` is allow by my dbms because I get better performance with the `LIKE`. And `toto.project.id_project` is a primary key and integer @jarlh

Comment: Is there much point OUTER JOINing tables from which you select no columns?

Comment: To which table does en_attente belong?

Comment: en_attente is on contact_groupe @Strawberry

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with your subquery. Those 17 lines that you've written are functionally identical to this, so why not use this instead?

```
SELECT DISTINCT g.id_contact_groupe  
           FROM contact_groupe g
           JOIN project p
             ON p.id_contact_groupe = g.id_contact_groupe 
          WHERE g.en_attente = 0
            AND p.id_project = 10 
            AND g.id_entreprise = 2
```